# Thunderbird default layout

Tags: thunderbird, display-settings, layout

I have used Thunderbird for a number of years. I have found it useful lately using tags to categorise emails, which I am working on.
As a Result, I have started using the `Group By Sort` option, so all emails are grouped by their relevant tag or group of tags.

I have been searching the web for a while trying to find the answer to this question but have now decided I am best posting here...

Currently, I am using `\` to collapse the groups so that they are all closed.
However, I need to keep doing this... If I navigate to a different mailbox and back, the groups reopen, and I need to close them again.

It's not a hard task as it's simply the press of 1 key `\`
It does get a bit annoying having to do it multiple times every hour.

Is there a way to set the `group by sort` layout to be `collpased as default`?

Comment: Try [this workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/803593/comments/38), after adapting it to your case, to make this setting "stick" to a folder.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for the link. That is essentially what I have been trying. However, my groups are constantly expanded Im trying to get them collapsed.
Also, `threadkey` is not available on my version of TB, not sure if that was maybe the main ingredient

Comment: This is a relatively old link, and threadkey is not what I was aiming at. The idea is to do the sort, view another folder, then redo the sort. The chances are slim that it will work. If it doesn't help, I fear that only the TB developers can help.

Comment: @harrymc nah it didnt sort, I need to collapse the groups every time I navigate back to the folder.

I seen a question raised for the same issue on mozilla. apparently it used to work the way Im wanting but since TB115 it stopped
The devs have not put up a response and the question was opened in August

Comment: **@ harrymc** Thanks for that link with workaround -- it worked just fine for me. I wanted other way around actually: to always have my "Group By Sort" (by Date, Desc) to be expanded. And that FINALLY worked (after it magically stopped at some point out of nowhere). The most funny thing: it still worked fine in another TB profile (2 accounts there), but only in some folders. Now that I have tried that workaround there as well, it works as I want in ALL places in both Thunderbird and Betterbird (latest 115.6 versions)